# Calculate a field's average after Mongo DB aggregate match and lookup query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two Mongo DB collections, *req* and *res*.

The format of *req* is -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("asdasdasdasdasd"),
    "req" : {
        "url" : "/some/url",
        "method" : "GET",
    },
    "fieldA" : "ABCPQR",
    "time" : "2016-08-05T00:02:25.633Z",
}
```

Collection *res* looks like this -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("jhtuyiogjhknmkvjhjkbhj"),
    "time" : "2016-08-05T00:00:11.272Z",
    "duration" : 106,
    "fieldB" : "ABCPQR"
}
```

What I want to do is.. For a certain kind of request, ie,  where *req.url* is same.. I want to calculate the average of *duration* field on *res* object.

So I aggregate the *res* obejcts like this -

```
db.req.aggregate([
    { $match : { 'req.url' : '/some/url' } },
    { $lookup : { from : 'res', localField : 'fieldA', foreignField : 'fieldB', as : 'combined'} },
])
```

This is what the output looks like -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("asdasdasdasdasd"),
    "req" : {
        "url" : "/device/apps/updates?sync=false",
        "method" : "POST",
    },
    "fieldA" : "34e92ab8-a037-4d39-b151-94cd3f1a34e7",
    "time" : "2016-08-05T00:00:11.166Z",
    "combined" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57b452b70be0f24aec4cc204"),
            "time" : "2016-08-05T00:00:11.272Z",
            "duration" : 106,
            "fieldB" : "34e92ab8-a037-4d39-b151-94cd3f1a34e7"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now to calculate, I added a *group* to the aggregation query -

```
db.req.aggregate([
    { $match : { 'req.url' : '/some/url' } },
    { $lookup : { from : 'res', localField : 'fieldA', foreignField : 'fieldB', as : 'combined'} },
    { $group: { _id: '$fieldA', avg : { $avg : '$combined.duration' } } }
])
```

But it produces no output at all. What am I doing wrong and how can I get the average of this *duration* field?

Comment: I tried your last query and it produced the result `{ "_id" : "ABCPQR", "avg" : null }`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)

> In the $group stage, if the expression resolves to an array, $avg
>   treats the operand as a non-numerical value.

and

> $avg ignores non-numeric values. If all operands for the average are
>   non-numeric, $avg returns null.

You can add [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage to deconstruct the array into multiple documents and then use `$avg` operator while grouping them

```
db.req.aggregate([
  { $match : { 'req.url' : '/some/url' } },
  { $lookup : { from : 'res', localField : 'fieldA', foreignField : 'fieldB', as : 'combined'} },
  { $unwind: '$combined' },
  { $group: { _id: 'avg_duration', avg : { $avg : '$combined.duration' } } }
]);
```

Comment: I see what _$unwind_ did there. But the result is still nothing. Should the __id_ be _null_ as I simply want the average of _duration_ field?

Comment: It depends on your collection. If you have documents with the same `req.url` and different `fieldA` values than grouping by `null` in last stage will produce another result than grouping by `fieldA`. But if you want the average duration of all requests identified only by `req.url` (without taking into account `fieldA`) value, then `null` will work.

Comment: Yes I understand.. null should give me the total average right? 
fieldA is unique, each value occurs only once in req and res collections both.

Comment: Yes, now I see. It seems that you need total average duration for particular request that is identified by `req.url` value and `fieldA` values indicate different responses of that request. In that case grouping should be performed by independent of response value (in particular `null`). I updated the answer.

Comment: Still no output. Tried with _id : null as well, no change.

Comment: Try it on 2 documents that you provided in your question. It gives me the correct result for them. If that's the issue than check how that documents differ from those in your collection. Or edit your question with real documents that you are trying query on.